# How to send data from S3 Bucket to FTP Server with help of Apache nifi?

Tags: postgresql, apache-nifi

I have file name and file path in SQL tables, files can be multiple for each row and this files are stored in S3 Bucket, now i want to send all those files via FTP whose name in sql rows? How we can achieve it via Apache nifi ?

I tried with get file and lists3 but not able to come to conclusion

Answer (score 0):

You need below components to develop your data ingestion pipeline:

- Processors

  - `QueryDatabaseTableRecord`: to query and get result data from database
  - `SplitText`: split query result line by line
  - `ExtractText`: get content of FlowFile into attribute
  - `UpdateAttibute`: derive S3 object key, bucket, FTP filename etc attributes
  - `FetchS3Object`: retrieves the contents of an S3 Object and writes it to the content of a FlowFile
  - `PutFTP`: sends FlowFiles to an FTP Server
- Controller Services:

  - `DBCPConnectionPool`: configure database instance connection, required by `QueryDatabaseTableRecord`
  - `CSVRecordSetWriter`: required by `QueryDatabaseTableRecord` to parse result dataset
  - `AWSCredentialsProviderControllerService`: configure AWS credentials, required for `FetchS3Object`

**Flow Design:**

Derive S3 and FTP attributes in one go at `UpdateAttibute`

`QueryDatabaseTableRecord -> SplitText -> ExtractText -> UpdateAttibute  -> FetchS3Object -> PutFTP`

All the processors are self-explanatory, so refer to official documentation for properties configuration.